# Calculating opposite X/Y vector

Tags: math, vector

[image]

Knowing "A" X,Y vector and its rotation, I would like to calculate "B" X,Y , assuming B is the opposite point in the diamond following a straight line.
"A" coordinates can be anywhere over the edge of the diamond and in the image A is facing north so let's say its rotation is 0.

Comment: Are you saying the vector is always vertical from the perspective you drew this from, but the rotation of the diamond with regards to the vector may change? I.e. with a rotation of 45 the diamond would be a square from our perspectives, and the entire right and left edges would be parallel to the vector

Comment: @RubenHelsloot no, you'll see what I am trying to do here is a continuous or infinite map, A represents the point where the actor leaves the map, and B which is what I am trying to figure how to calculate is the point when it reappears. The diamond is just the map boundaries. As stated, A x/y can be anywhere over them.

Comment: Please note I mentioned I can know A rotation, that determines the angle of the straight line I would need to calculate B vector.

Comment: Are the corners 90 degrees?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot yes.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two possibilities. Either `B` is on an adjacent side of the square, like how you drew it, or it reaches the opposite end of the square. In the first case, you have one corner in between the two points, call that `C`. Now the rotation `r` of the square influences the angle of the corner CAB as `45 - r` degrees, if `r < 45`. Then you can say that the length `BC` can be calculated using `BC = AC * tan(45 - r)` if I remember high school maths correctly.

If we call the length of each side of the square X, there must be a point in rotating the square where B aligns perfectly with the opposing corner, so `BC = X`. From that point onward, you cannot calculate `BC` as straightforwardly anymore, but you can calculate where it *would* have been had the square been infinitely large. If you calculate that possible value `BC'`, you can then say that's too large for the square by a ratio `BC' / X`. But if we draw an imaginary line parallel to `BC'`, on `X / BC'`th of the way between `C` and `A`, then the point where that line crosses the opposing side of the square is the location of `B`.

Finally, for `r = 45`, the line is parallel to the square, so `B` can be easily calculated, and for `r > 45`, the mirror image of this entire procedure can be repeated.

I hope I didn't lose you in these calculations, I recommend you take a piece of paper and try drawing them out